# Having issues finding the options to lower Quality with Animation Codec

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to find if its possible to specify quality when converting to animation codec.

I've used this bit of code and don't see anything about quality.

```
ffmpeg -h encoder=qtrle
```

I know this is my generic command to get to animation codec

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -codec copy -c:v qtrle output.mov
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Animation encoder has no quality or bitrate options. It is a lossless encoder which implements Run Length Encoding and a fixed procedure for compression with no variables for ratecontrol.